# How to eval an expression using FD redirection in bash

Tags: bash

I am writting a bash boilerplate to reuse in our internal projects.  One of the features is an output function supporting noop, debug and logging to file.  This works fine until I try to use it when redirecting the output.  Here is my current version of my code along with an example that fails:

```
function output () {
  if [ "$NOOP" == 'true' ]; then
      if [ "$DEBUG" == 'true' ]; then
          echo "$1" |& tee -a $LOGFILE
      else
          echo "$1"
      fi
  else
      if [ "$DEBUG" == 'true' ]; then
          echo "Command: $1" |& tee -a $LOGFILE
          ( $1 ) |& tee -a $LOGFILE
      else
          ( $1 ) 2>&1 >> $LOGFILE
      fi
  fi    
}

output "echo test > test.log"
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer is in your title: use `eval`.

Comment: Indeed,   ( eval $1 ) 2>&1 >> $LOGFILE works as expected.

Comment: Quote the variable, and there's no need to put it in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell metacharacters are not processed after expanding a variable, except for word splitting and filename wildcards. So characters like `>` and `;` don't have any special meaning there.

As you said in your title, you need to use `eval`.

```
function output () {
  if [ "$NOOP" == 'true' ]; then
      if [ "$DEBUG" == 'true' ]; then
          echo "$1" |& tee -a $LOGFILE
      else
          echo "$1"
      fi
  else
      if [ "$DEBUG" == 'true' ]; then
          echo "Command: $1" |& tee -a $LOGFILE
          eval "$1" |& tee -a $LOGFILE
      else
          eval "$1" 2>&1 >> $LOGFILE
      fi
  fi    
}
```